# Duplicated values using INNER JOIN in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

i have 3 tables, i want to get the total sum, but im not getting the right results.

First table(investors)

```
id investor_id 

1     27
2     27
3     29
4     30
5     31
```

Second table(payments)

```
id investor_id

1   27
2   27
3   28
4   29
5   30
6   31
7   27
```

Third table(billed)

```
id payments_id billed

1      1        189
2      2        300   
3      3        500
4      4        700
5      5        200
6      6        300
```

HERE is my query

```
SELECT SUM(billed.billed)
FROM billed AS billed
INNER JOIN payments AS payments ON billed.payments_id = payments.id
INNER JOIN investors AS investors ON payments.investor_id = investors.investor_id
```

instead of getting `1689` only, im getting a results of `2178`

i am really stuck with my answer is there really a way to do this just by using query only?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the total sum for bills, just query that table directly, no need to join:

```
SELECT SUM(billed) FROM billed
```

If for some reason you need to `JOIN`, the I select the distinct investors in a subquery, then join it:

```
SELECT SUM(billed.billed)
FROM billed AS billed
INNER JOIN payments AS payments ON billed.payments_id = payments.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISCTINCT investors FROM investors) AS investors ON payments.investor_id = investors.investor_id
```

Comment: i need to use JOIN because, the SUM of billed will depend on the investor table.